# Listen for apk installation status in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, installation, package, apk

I'm new to Android Kotlin. Currently, I'm building an app store and I don't know how to listen for the successful or failed installation status throughout the entire activities and fragments.

I'm using **startActivityForResult** with **Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE** to initiate the installation and **onActivityResult** to listen for success or failure events. However, I've realized that when I switch to a different Activity or Fragment, they won't be able to listen to that event to update the interface. Is there a way to make all of them listen to this event? I've researched that registering a BroadcastReceiver with
**android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL** and
**android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED**
in Manifest can listen for a successful installation event, but what if the user cancels the installation?

What's the most optimal way to handle this issue? Please let me know, I've been stuck for a few days now.